# Python, looking to extract values from a masked array, then rebuild an array

Tags: python, numpy

I’m currently writing something that involves a lot of noise I’m attempting to remove, but in order do this I initially used masks, but the way in which I’m analysing the data breaks using a mask.

The masking is done, I’m looking to extract the data that is not masked, run analysis on this, then rebuild the array with the original order.

```
array([[3, 0, 3],
       [6, 7, 2],
       [2, 5, 0],
       [2, 1, 4]])
```

Make Mask

```
array([[-, -, -],
       [6, 7, 2],
       [-, -, -],
       [2, 1, 4]])
```

Extract Values

```
array([[6, 7, 2],
       [2, 1, 4]])
```

Do analysis

Rebuild Array

```
array([[-, -, -],
       [6, 7, 2],
       [-, -, -],
       [2, 1, 4]])
```

I’m hoping for an efficient way of doing this as I’m dealing with 100 million data points. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked into [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)? They are commonly used to digest [or filter](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/filtering_lists.html) one list into another.

Comment: Thank you, I was just about to edit this, as I'm currently looking at compressed() which I think is doing what I need.

Its not exactly what I need, but I think I'll be able to do it with other arguments and commands now that I have the x.compressed() command functioning.

Then I was able to reshape the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use

```
masked[~masked.mask] = analyzed.ravel()
```

to reassign the analyzed values to the masked array.

---

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[3, 0, 3],
                [6, 7, 2],
                [2, 5, 0],
                [2, 1, 4]])

masked = np.ma.masked_array(arr, mask=False)
masked.mask[::2, None] = True

extracted = np.ma.compress_rows(masked)

analyzed = extracted*10

masked[~masked.mask] = analyzed.ravel()

print(masked)
```

yields

```
[[-- -- --]
 [60 70 20]
 [-- -- --]
 [20 10 40]]
```

Comment: Thank you, I've tried this but it appears that compress_rows() is hanging spyder.

The way I was able to do it was 

masked.compressed()

Which then creates a flattened array, but I just reshape it back into what I need.

Otherwise everything else is very useful thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Masked arrays have a `compress(ed)` method that extracts the unmasked values - as a 1d array (since in general masking can be irregular).  But I'm not sure about ways of putting new values back in the original (or an array with the same shape and mask). (looks like unutbu has that step covered)

Many masked methods use `filled()` to convert the data, temporarily, into something regular numpy methods work with.  For example a masked version of `sum` can replace the masked values with 0.  A product with 1s.  The appropriate fill value will differ with the operation.

```
In [86]: Am=np.ma.masked_less(A,3)

In [87]: Am
Out[87]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[3 -- 3]
 [6 7 --]
 [-- 5 --]
 [-- -- 4]],
             mask =
 [[False  True False]
 [False False  True]
 [ True False  True]
 [ True  True False]],
       fill_value = 999999)

In [88]: Am.compressed()
Out[88]: array([3, 3, 6, 7, 5, 4])

In [89]: Am.filled(999)
Out[89]: 
array([[  3, 999,   3],
       [  6,   7, 999],
       [999,   5, 999],
       [999, 999,   4]])
```

Square the non-masked values:

```
In [97]: Am[~Am.mask]=Am.compressed()**2

In [98]: Am
Out[98]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[9 -- 9]
 [36 49 --]
 [-- 25 --]
 [-- -- 16]],
             mask =
 [[False  True False]
 [False False  True]
 [ True False  True]
 [ True  True False]],
       fill_value = 999999)

In [99]: Am.data
Out[99]: 
array([[ 9,  0,  9],
       [36, 49,  2],
       [ 2, 25,  0],
       [ 2,  1, 16]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to keep the array structure you can extract the values by just using:

```
masked = ... # your masked array
valid_points = masked[~masked.mask]
```

or if a simple array suffices:

```
valid_points_simple_array = valid_points.data
```

This will now be 1D neglecting any previous shape it had because NumPy cannot know if it can keep any shape (because every dimension must have the same number of arguments). But there are some functions if you know you only want to keep valid rows/columns but in general it would be just a matter of reshaping your array again:

```
# Only complete rows were discarded
reshaped_valid = valid_points.reshape(masked.shape[0], valid_points.size / masked.shape[0])
```

or

```
# or in case for  columns
reshaped_valid = valid_points.reshape(valid_points.size / masked.shape[1], masked.shape[1])
```

this only works if you only excluded complete rows or columns! Don't use it if you don't need the shape of your array though.

Then you can do whatever you want with `reshaped_valid` and if you have done any changes you can simply assign it to your original array again:

```
masked[~masked.mask] = reshaped_valid # maybe you need to use .ravel() not sure...
```

---

Sorry for the late answer and the other answers are probably better but I had some internet connection problems but I didn't want to discard it either...